# Installing second OS on TrueCrypt encrypted disk

Tags: installation, multi-boot, encryption, truecrypt

I have a machine running Vista 64bit and disk with three partitions fully encrypted with [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).
I want to install Windows 7 as my second OS, but i'm not sure if this would work because of disk encryption.

Any experiences running dual boot systems and TrueCrypt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, I've had Windows XP and Ubuntu with TrueCrypt on my home PC. Never had any experience with Vista or Windows 7, but [this fellow](http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3174721) did it, so it's possible.

You will have to decrypt both the system partition and partition where you are going to install Windows 7. Go to "*System > Permanently decrypt system partition / drive*" menu and then follow the instructions in the wizard. If I remember it right, there wasn't any way to decrypt non-system partition, so you can just format it. After that, install Windows 7 and encrypt both system partitions again.

It's a bit cumbersome, but there is no other way :]

Comment: I'm now convinced that this is possible, but way too complicated and time consuming. Virtualization, here i come :)

Comment: Seems silly not to have thought of this in the first place, but this is the appropriate solution for loading in another OS in a TrueCrypt environment. As cumbersome as it may be, it is a one-time process for achieving this level of OS encryption with the flexibility of dual boot options. I can't imagine people would be changing around their installations for it to not be worth considering. Permanently decrypt, OS and multiboot configuration, partition re-encrypt. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am no expert in this area, I would have to say this cannot be done.

Seeing it is only software-based encryption, when you install Windows 7 on the partition, the encryption would be removed (or you would not be able to install without repartitioning).